# Measurability of a specific function

Tags: measure-theory

In the situation where I have a finite kernel(in each $x\in D$) $\Lambda$ from $ D\times \mathcal{E}$ with $P(x,\cdot) \ll \Lambda(x,\cdot)$ where $P$ is also a finite kernel on the same space. We know  $L^1(\Lambda,E)$ is separable with dense countable subset $H$. Here $(D,\mathcal{D}),(E,\mathcal{E})$are measurable spaces. I can establish a Radon-Nikodym derivative(RND) $\rho$ such that 
$$\sup_{A \in \mathcal{E}_0}\int_{A} \rho_{x}(y)-h(y) d\Lambda(x,dy) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}  $$ 
let's call this (1).
where $\mathcal{E}_0$ is a generator for $\mathcal{E}$,  $h \in H$ and

$$\frac{dP}{d\Lambda}=\frac{P(x,dy)}{\Lambda(x,dy)}=:\rho_{x} (y)$$

Enumerating $H$, we can write $H=\{h_m|m\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Now 
define $m_n(x):= min\{k \in \mathbb{N}|(1)\textrm{ is satisfied for }\epsilon = 2^{-n+1}  \textrm{ and } h=h_k\}$ , I want to see whether this function is $\mathcal{D}-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{N})$-measurable. But it seems that even though I have this much information I cannot describe the preimage of a natural number under $m$ in an insightful way. Can someone help here?